# How can i convert my GMT time into IST of 12 hour format in android?

Tags: android, time

Explanation:
           I have time in GMT format i need to convert into IST. I did already but for 24 hour i want to get in 12 hour format with AM/PM.

here is my code

```
DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm'+00':ss");

utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
Date date1;
date1=utcFormat.parse(time);
Log.e("IST",""+date1.toString());//After convert in IST i got Sat Mar 26 19:30:00 GMT+05:30 2016

Date timestamp;
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
timestamp = utcFormat.parse(time);
Log.e("timestamp", "" + timestamp.toString()); //After convert in UTC i got Sat Mar 26 19:30:00 GMT+05:30 2016
Log.e("Time",""+time.toString());//This is my time 2016-03-26T14:00+00:00
```

Problem is i got the same time for IST and GMT.
What will i need to do so than i will get a time in 12 hours???

Please help me to solve out this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the `Date` class does not hold any actual timezone information, it is just a `long` millisecond value from UNIX epoch time. And the `TimeZone` of the `SimpleDateFormat` is only relevant when you *display* the date, not when you parse it. So in order to print your `Date` as an IST date, you must use that format when printing the `Date`:

```
// Parse your time string
DateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm'+00':ss");
Date date = myFormat.parse(time);

// Set a new format for displaying your time
DateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));

// This will print the IST time in the format specified: 2016-03-25T09:42:07+5:30
String istTime = isoFormat.format(date);
Log.d(istTime);
```

As for the 12 hour format, you can set that with a new [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) when you print the time.

```
/**
 * 'hh' is the 12-hour time format, while 'HH' is the 24-hour format
 * 'hh' will always print two digits, while 'h' will drop leading zeros
 * 'a' is the AM/PM marker
 */
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

// This will print the current time, for example: 09:42 AM
Log.d(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

---

Android also has a helpful [`DateUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) class, that will format the `Date` based on the settings of the current device.

Comment: i got an exception parseException.

Comment: I want to parse my time variable value into DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a"); format Is it possible?

Comment: @MilanGajera No, if I am understanding you correctly. Your `time` variable is a `String` that you want to parse to get a `Date` object. To parse that `String`, you must use a `SimpleDateFormat` that matches that format. A `Date` object does not contain any formatting information, it is literally just a `long` value (the value you get from `date.getTime()`), all of the other methods are just simple modifications of that `long` value. If you want any other representation of the `Date` object, you must use another `SimpleDateFormat` object to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here i was created a another object of DateFormat and pass a parameter inside it' constructor.

```
//hh:mm a format of 12 hour with leading 0 before the hours, mm is for minutes and (a) is for AM/PM format.
//where as HH is provides the format of 24 hours.
```

Here i got a 12 hours format.

```
DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm'+00':ss");
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

String ist=outputFormat.format(utcFormat.parse(time));
```